# HTML Mouse Over how to get rid of whitespace?

Tags: html, css, mouseover

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EaG6G.png)

As you can see from the above image i have inserted a mouse over "I" Logo but its keeps leaving a bit of white space under the text is there a way to eliminate this?

UPDATE: [UPDATE PICTURE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JOFi3.png)

Now the issue I have is when I try post on the third row in its pushes the "I" down under the text

updated code below

```css
  label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 84px;
}

span#typePrompt {
  display: block;
  line-height: 1;
}

.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -60px;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black transparent transparent transparent;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
  span# {
    display: block;
    line-height: 1;
  }
```

```html
<td style="width: 253.55pt; border-top: none; border-left: none; border-bottom: 1pt solid #c9c9c9; border-right: 1pt solid #c9c9c9; background: #ededed; padding: 0cm 5.4pt; height: 16.7pt; vertical-align: top;">
  <p style="line-height: normal; font-size: 15px; font-family: 'Calibri',sans-serif; margin: 0cm;"><strong><span style="font-size: 19px; color: black;">
<span>Max Reach   </span><div class="tooltip">
<span>Ⓘ</span><span class="tooltiptext">Maximum cable distance for SR modules is 2m</span>
</div></span></strong></p>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Nest `Ⓘ` in it's own `span` and set it to `display: block;` with `line-height: 1;`.

```css
label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 84px;
}

span#typePrompt {
  display: none;
}

.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}

.tooltip > span.info {
  display: block;
  line-height: 1;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -60px;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black transparent transparent transparent;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
}
/*for SO demo */
body {
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <td style="width: 261.95pt; border-top: 1pt solid #c9c9c9; border-left: none; border-bottom: 1.5pt solid #c9c9c9; border-right: 1pt solid #c9c9c9; padding: 0cm 5.4pt; height: 16.7pt; vertical-align: top;">
    <span>Max Reach&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>

    <div class="tooltip"><span class="info">Ⓘ</span><span class="tooltiptext">Maximum cable distance for SR modules is 2m</span>
    </div>
</body>
```

Works the exact same...

```css
label {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 84px;
}

span#typePrompt {
  display: block;
  line-height: 1;
}

.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: black;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 1;
  bottom: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -60px;
}

.tooltip .tooltiptext::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 100%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: black transparent transparent transparent;
}

.tooltip:hover .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
}

  span.info {
    display: block;
    line-height: 1;
  }
```

```html
<td style="width: 253.55pt; border-top: none; border-left: none; border-bottom: 1pt solid #c9c9c9; border-right: 1pt solid #c9c9c9; background: #ededed; padding: 0cm 5.4pt; height: 16.7pt; vertical-align: top;">
  <p style="line-height: normal; font-size: 15px; font-family: 'Calibri',sans-serif; margin: 0cm;"><strong><span style="font-size: 19px; color: black;">
<span>Max Reach   </span><div class="tooltip">
<span class="info">Ⓘ</span><span class="tooltiptext">Maximum cable distance for SR modules is 2m</span>
</div></span></strong></p>
</td>
```

Comment: Hey this worked perfectly for the Cells that are not in bold but when i try to put this code in one of the Bold Cells it still does the same well actually it puts the "i" under the text its like there is a invisible <br> in there  :(. thank you for getting back to me though

Comment: @SamC-WT what is a "bold cell"? Update your question with the code you are referring to. If I don't have the code it's impossible for me to know what you're talking about.

Comment: Oh sorry yeah ill upload it give me 5

Comment: @SamC-WT I updated my answer with the updated code you just posted. It works the exact same. Just need to clean up your formatting issues in the CSS and assign that span with the class `.info`. If this doesn't work, edit the snippet I added to your question to look the exact same as the screenshot you posted. I cannot debug screenshots, sorry.

Comment: @SamC-WT get it to work?

Comment: So i have but i haven't if that makes sense

<p style="line-height: normal; font-size: 15px; font-family: 'Calibri',sans-serif; margin: 0cm;">

if i remove the following line then it will all stay together but it gets rid of my font settings cant seem to have both